# Sum operator precedence

Tags: summation, operator-theory, products

I'm trying to read some simple equations and in order to interpret them in the right way I need to know $\sum$ and $\prod $ operator range/precedence.

$$ \sum p(s, a) +\gamma $$

is equal to $\sum(p(s,a) + \gamma)$ or $\sum(p(s,a)) + \gamma$.

The same question is for product operator.

Also, for UCB1 formula

$$ A_t = \underset{a\in\mathcal{A}}{\operatorname{argmax}} Q_t(a) + \sqrt{\frac{2\log t}{N_t(a)}}$$

should I treat it like this

$$ A_t = \underset{a\in\mathcal{A}}{\operatorname{argmax}}\Bigl( Q_t(a) + \sqrt{\frac{2\log t}{N_t(a)}} \Bigr) $$

or like this?

$$ A_t = \underset{a\in\mathcal{A}}{\operatorname{argmax}}\Bigl( Q_t(a) \Bigr) + \sqrt{\frac{2\log t}{N_t(a)}}  $$

Could you please clarify those for me?

Comment: For $A_t$ it is the first option since the root term depends on $a$ which is iterated by $\text{argmax}$. In other words $a$ cannot appear outside $\text{argmax}$ like it does in the second option. For the sum I think it depends on the context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The $\sum$ operator  and $+$  have the same precedence level, so
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum p(s, a) +\gamma &=\left(\sum p(s,a)\right)+\gamma
> \end{align*}
>   contrary to
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum p(s, a) \cdot\gamma &=\sum \left(p(s,a)\cdot\gamma\right)
> \end{align*}
>
> The $\max$ operator binds stronger than the $+$ operator, so
>   \begin{align*}
> \underset{a\in\mathcal{A}}{\operatorname{argmax}} Q_t(a) + \sqrt{\frac{2\log t}{N_t(a)}}
> &=\left(\underset{a\in\mathcal{A}}{\operatorname{argmax}} Q_t(a)\right) + \sqrt{\frac{2\log t}{N_t(a)}}
> \end{align*}

*Hint:* You might find chapter 2: *Sums* in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)* by R.L. Graham, D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik helpful. It provides a thorough introduction in the usage of sums.